# How to add a Banner to a specific Project on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

We have moved our project to a different organization on Azure Devops. For those visiting the old project, we want to display a banner notifying the user of our new location.

I have found this documentation online to add a banner:
https://microsoft.visualstudio.com/_settings/ms-eswm.banner-settings-hub.hub

However we only want the banner to apply to the project, not the entire organization. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add a Banner to a specific Project on Azure Devops

For this issue, I am afraid this is currently impossible to achieve in azure devops. Azure DevOps enables you to put a banner message on the top of the browser window to display a message. **Every page** on Azure DevOps will show this message until the user closes the banner bar, or the message expires.

There are two ways to add a banner: Banner Settings Extension and [Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-banners?view=azure-devops). Neither of these two ways can only add a banner to a specific project. The parameter of the specified project is not provided in the az devops cli.

[image]

So currently, you can only write the project that needs the user's attention in the banner message. In addition, you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.